# predicting using only certain terms in a mixed-model regression via lmer or glmer via predict()

Tags: mixed-model, predictive-models

When using lm() or glm(), the predict.lm() or predict.glm() functions allow one to obtain predictions from the model using only a subset of the predictor variables, while setting the coefficients of the others to zero.  For instance, fit<-lm(y~x1+x2) then predict(fit,type="terms",terms="x1") will give the predicted values of y given x1, while holding x2 constant at zero.  There does not seem to be the same option for mixed-model regressions from lmer or glmer via the pred.merMod.  Does someone know of a work-around to do this; preferably another function that already exists?

Comment: Serious question - why would you want to hold all other predictors at 0? Take a look at `marginaleffects`, `ggeffects`, and `emmeans`. These all do something like what you are asking and have handy graphing functions to visualize the results.

Comment: The predict.lm code predict(fit,type="terms",terms="x1") gives the predicted values using the calculated slope for x1 while setting all other slope values to zero.  Actually, I don't need the other slopes to be set to zero, only marginalizing the other variables so that their effects become absorbed into the intercept.  I think that the ggeffects package might do what I want.  Thanks.